# savitzky-Golay filter in python, wrong window size

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing

I have a time series data I want to smooth using Savitzgy Golay filter. According to resaerch here:
https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1808/1808.10489.pdf

Window size should be n+2 where n -> polyorder.
I performed such smoothing on my data but I see no results in by signal. Have I chosen wrong window size?

My data is EMG signal with `(50858, 2)` shape having `t` and `emg` columns, where emg is value to be denoised. Here is the head of it.

[image]

Filter implementation:

`Y= data.iloc[:,1].values` 
`Y_filtered= savgol_filter(Y, window_length = 5, polyorder = 3)`
And plotting it:

```
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(Y[-1000:])
plt.title("EMG with noise")


plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(Y_filtered[-1000:])
plt.title("SG filter applied ")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried Higher window sizes? it does look like it has had affect as it looks like the higher frequency noise is smaller, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: my goal is to denoise emg signal with different approaches, one of them is SG, therefore i asked.

Comment: what do you consider noise? emg contains a lot of information which can be considered useful or noise

Comment: I don't know exactly as it is not my field of engineering. As I understand it right now noise can be unwanted signal from moving wires or its instability or electrode contact can noise my EMG and I want to remove it.

Comment: without any application in mind, deciding the size of the window is really up to the visual appeal - alternatively you could apply the Fourier and demonstrate that frequencies outside the domain of the EMG have been suppressed or frequencies such as mains noise 50Hz (or 60Hz in the US/saudi) are suppressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window size is not restricted to be `n+2`. It has to be odd, though. I have tried with `window_size=21` and `polyorder=3` and it works.
I think it is unlikely that you will see results with a window size = 5 in a multithousand samples signal, because probably your noise spans more samples. Give it a try and use a bigger window size.

Answer (score 0):

"**Window size should be n+2 where n -> polyorder**" is an incorrect statement. Rather window size should be at least n+2 to see some kind of smoothing happening. If m is the window size and n is the polyorder then you are effectively trying to estimate (n + 1) coefficients using m data points. It would be ideal to have the window size much larger than the polyorder. Otherwise the smoothed curve would be a curve that follows the input data, including any noise in it.